# My code is producing incorrect result. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

My apologies up front for the long thread.

I am very flabbergasted as to why this code is  not working correctly.

Please have a look.

On markup,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="cancelBtn" style="width:105px;padding:5px;margin:5px;" runat="server" CommandName="delete"  OnDataBinding="btnDelete_DataBinding" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");' Text="Cancel Training" />
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then I have a function called `getDateDifference()` As Boolean with code below:

```
Private Function getDateDifference() As Boolean
    Dim username = Session("Username")
    Dim myConnectionString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)

    myConnection.Open()

    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select  DateDiff(dd,GetDate(),d.trainingDates) as DaysCount " & _
                                           "from tblTrainings t Inner Join tblCourses c on t.courseId = c.courseId " & _
                                           "Inner Join tblLocations l on t.locationId = l.LocationId " & _
                                           "Inner Join tblTrainingDates d on t.dateid=d.dateid " & _
                                           "Inner Join tblCourseInstructor ic on c.courseId = ic.CourseId " & _
                                           "Inner Join tblInstructors i on ic.instructorId = i.instructorId " & _
                                           "Inner Join tblLogin lg on t.username = lg.username where lg.username =  @username", myConnection)
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    If dr1.Read() Then
        Dim DaysCount As Integer = dr1("DaysCount")
        Response.Write(DaysCount)
        If DaysCount >= 2 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

The function is invoked below:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("cancelBtn"), Button)
        btn.Enabled = Not getDateDifference()
    End If
End Sub
```

All we trying do to is compare trainingdates with current date.

If current date is within 24 hours (or 2 days) of training date, a user who has already signed up for a class, cannot cancel that class.

The user can cancel if current date is more than 2 days before training date.

To test, I have 2 trainings scheduled on my account.

One training date is 6/22/2013

The other training date is 6/29/2013.

When I run the query above, I get 1, and 8 days respectively.

This is correct because today's date is 6/21/2013 which is there is one day left before first training date of 6/22/2013 and 8 days left
  before the second training date of 6/29/2013.

This means that on my app (please see screenshot), I expect to see one button disabled and the other enabled.
  ![enter image description here][1]
  As you can see from screenshot, this is not happening. Both are either getting enabled or disabled no matter what the training date is.

When I try to debug DaysCount with response.write (DaysCount), it shows **11**.

Not sure how this is happening. It has been at least 3 days since I have been struggling with this.

DB is sql server 2005. However production db is 2008.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: So what can you exclude? The query works in SSMS and in code during debugging and the button gets disabled/enabled correctly on debugging? So it's just rendered wrong? From where and when do you databind the grid? Side-note: `getDateDifference` should return the number of days instead. Then it would be more flexible and reeadable: `btn.Enabled = getDateDifference() > 2`

Comment: It's 2013 people... Ahh I want to cry.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in RowDataBound, where it calls getDateDifference, does it return True and False for those rows?  I'm just wondering if your question is more about it setting Enabled to True on one of the buttons, but the button is getting rendered as disabled no matter what.  Also, I agree with Tim on making the function more readable.

Comment: TimSchmelter, look at the screenshot, there are 2 days. One says 6/22/2013. The button for this date is supposed to be disabled because it is within 2 days
of training because the app owners don't want training canceled. 

The second date is 6/29/2013. There are still 8 days left before training. This means the user has ample time to cancel training if s/he wishes to do so.

However, as you can see both are disabled.

@MattWilko, I had code similar to that before I switched it off to the new code I am using now.

I am about to try yours and see if it makes a difference this time.

Comment: Please show how to make it more readable. I thought using {} would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is happening here, but to try and debug it I would just return `d.trainingDates` from your database query instead of doing the `DateDiff`, and then do this to validate it:

```
If dr1.Read() Then
    Dim trngDate As Date = dr1("trainingDates")
    Response.Write(trngDate.ToString)
    If (trngDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays >= 2 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End If
```

**EDIT**

But - why not just compare the dates in the RowDataBound event.

There is no need to perform another query, the date your are comparing is in the row you are binding

Something like this (untested) code:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim dateValue As Date = Date.Parse(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Dates")))
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("cancelBtn"), Button)
        btn.Enabled = (dateValue - DateTime.Now).TotalDays >= 2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to dump any more stuff than I have already but I ran your code and now both buttons are enabled which was what my original code that is similar to yours was doing.
And also, when I ran that debugger again on Response.write(trngDate.ToString()), I get `6/22/2013 12:00:00 AM6/22/2013 12:00:00 AM`

Notice that the 6/29/2013 date isn't showing up.

Comment: Well I suspect that your query to find the Dates column and your query to find the difference between the date are not the same.

Comment: are you suggesting to remove the code from function and put in rowDataBound event?

I will take any suggestion I can get right now.

Comment: YEEEEEEEESSSSSSS @MattWilko. YOU DID IT!!!!

Thank you, thank you, thank you.

It worked!!!!!

WOW, I am so excited for a peaceful weekend - all thanks to you.

I hope you are awarded maximum points for solving this. You are great.

Answer (score 1):

I know you accepted @Matt Wilko's answer, but just to answer the specific problem you're facing:-

The problem is that your query returns all `tblTraining` records for the user. There is no condition in the where clause to determine which `tblTraining` record is the current active one.

`Response.Write(DaysCount)` did not produce 11, but rather produced 1 and 1, which is the difference between 6/22/2013 and 6/21/2013. You had 2 rows, so each digit must have been for a different row, and both rows seems to be getting the same date difference.

You will probably need to declare `Private Function getDateDifference(courseId as Integer) As Boolean` or something similar, so that you can pass the `courseId` to the function and use it in your SQL statement to identify the specific training program that you want. Probably your SQL statement will look something like

```
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(_
    "select  DateDiff(dd,GetDate(),d.trainingDates) as DaysCount " & _
    "from tblTrainings t Inner Join tblCourses c on t.courseId = c.courseId " & _
    "Inner Join tblLocations l on t.locationId = l.LocationId " & _
    "Inner Join tblTrainingDates d on t.dateid=d.dateid " & _
    "Inner Join tblCourseInstructor ic on c.courseId = ic.CourseId " & _
    "Inner Join tblInstructors i on ic.instructorId = i.instructorId " & _
    "Inner Join tblLogin lg on t.username = lg.username " & _
    "where lg.username =  @username and " & _
    "t.courseId = @courseId", myConnection)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseId", courseId)
```

As to where you can get your `courseId`, you can probably use the approach @Matt Wilko used. But then again, his method would have avoided this whole issue altogether.

Comment: thank you for your thoughts and code.

I promise to try that in some way. At this point, when it isn't broke, I would rather not mess with it.